# Prove that $\sqrt{2}>1$

Tags: axioms

I need to prove that $\sqrt{2}>1$, but the initial assumption I am given is that $\sqrt{2}>0$.  I have $\sqrt{2}>0$ so $2>0$ (multiply by $\sqrt{2}$ on each side). I don't know what my next step should be. We are supposed to use axioms and what not. The axioms that we are supposed to use are the 15 basic complete field axioms, such as associativity, commutativity, inverses, identity, etc..

Comment: That's the definition of $\sqrt{x}$ - it is the positive value $y$ such that $y^2=x$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It's the *non-negative* value, otherwise $\sqrt{0}$ wouldn't be defined.  Just nitpicking.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean *ordered field*, not *complete field* there...

Answer (score 5):

We know, by the usual ordering axioms, that $2 = 1+1>1$.

Now, suppose that $\sqrt{2} \leq 1$.  It would follow that 
$$
\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2} \leq 1 \cdot 1
$$
since given positive $a,b,c,d$, we have $a\leq c$ and $b\leq d$ implies $ab \leq cd$.  However, this leads to the conclusion
$$
2 \leq 1
$$
Which is a contradiction.

Comment: What if we are not working by Peanos axioms? What if all that we know is that $\sqrt2>0$?

Comment: @Emin do you mean to say that $1>0$ might not be given?

Comment: I mean what if it is not given that 2>1 (but I think it is equivalent with your question).

Comment: @Emin the step I've skipped for brevity is $$1>0 \implies 1+1 > 1+0$$ that $1>0$ is usually one of the axioms given for an ordered field.

Comment: @Emin sometimes you are equivalently given $a>0$ and $b>0 \implies ab>0$.  In this case, we may state $1$ is positive. Proof: either $1$ is positive or $−1$ is positive. If $−1$ is positive, then $(−1)(−1) = 1$ is positive, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Emin: What do the Peano axioms have to do with that?

Comment: By Peano axioms we prove that 1+1=2 which was used in his prove!

Comment: @Emin once you've defined "$1$" and "$+$", $2$ is defined by $2 = 1+1$, and arbitrary integers are defined by $$ n = \overbrace{1 + \cdots + 1}^n$$ regardless of which axioms it took to get to that point.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom 1 and + are defined, but 2=1+1 is not a definition! It is a theorem. It is a consequence from Peanos axioms!

Comment: The only difference with Peano's axioms is that we **define** (and yes, it most certainly *is* a definition) $2 = S(1) = 1+1$, where $a+1:=S(a)$.

Comment: We define 2 as a successor of 1, but we don't define 2 as 2=1+1. We prove that 2=1+1.

Comment: If that's your only hangup, then all you need to say is $a + 1 = a + S(0) = S(a + 0) = S(a)$, per the recursive definition of addition.  However, this question makes no mention of Peno's axioms, and it is not generally required that one appeal to them in dealing with ordered fields.

Comment: Now I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt2+2>0$ since both $2$ and $\sqrt2$ are positive. If we prove that $2>\sqrt{2}$ than we've proven that $\sqrt2>1$ (because from $2>\sqrt{2}$ we have $2\sqrt{2}>2$ or $\sqrt{2}>1$). Let we suppose that $2<\sqrt{2}$, than $\sqrt2-2>0$. Now from $\sqrt2+2>0$ and $\sqrt2-2>0$ we have that $2-4>0$ or $-2>0$ or $2<0$ which is contradictory with $2>0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $0 \leq x \leq 1$, then you also have $0 \leq x^2 \leq 1$. But $\left(\sqrt2\right)^2 = 2 > 1$, so...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, but at the time it didn't include the part about field axioms...

Comment: i said we are supposed to use axioms when I first asked the question, the basic ones are pretty universal to begin with

Comment: @jack If you want a formal proof that start from just the axioms, you'll have to *state* the axioms. There are different ways to write some of the axioms, and while the gist of the proof will always be the same, the details may vary. Also, as I pointed out in another comment, if you start from *just* the axioms, $2$ isn't even defined... So your question did, in multiple ways, implie that you're not looking for a completely formal proof...

Answer (score 0):

It's really not possible to give a satisfactory answer to this question without knowing exactly what the 15 axioms are to which the OP refers and which theorems (the OP's "whatnot") have already been proved from them and are at our disposal, but presumably one theorem says that if $0\lt a$ and $b\lt c$, then $ab\lt ac$.  From that one can argue that if $0\lt x\lt1$ then $x\cdot0\lt x\cdot x\lt x\cdot1$.  The theorems or axioms saying $x\cdot0=0$ and $x\cdot1=x$ turn this into $0\lt x\lt 1\implies0\lt x^2\lt1$.  If you now know that $1\lt2$ then you can conclude that $0\lt x\lt1\implies x^2\not=2$.  Combining this with the assumption $\sqrt2\gt0$ gives $\sqrt2\ge1$, so all you have to note is that $\sqrt2\not=1$ (since $1^2=1\not=2$).  But to do all this, or something like it, formally, you need to be able to cite the exact axioms and whatnot you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $1>0$ (because $1$ is a square), so $3=1+1+1 > 0+0+0=0$. On the other hand, you have $$3=4-1=(\sqrt{2}-1)(\sqrt{2}+1).$$ So you know that $$(\sqrt{2}-1)(\sqrt{2}+1)>0 \ \text{and} \ \sqrt{2}+1>1+0=1>0,$$ hence (by dividing) $$\sqrt{2}-1>0, \ \text{ie.} \ \sqrt{2}>1.$$